# How to get data after passing parameters between UWP pages

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

I have create an UWP app using Template 10 framework. I have a GridView with a list of movies and I want to able to navigate to the MovieDetailPage when I click on a movie on the grid.
This is my code for the grid item click event

```
private void moviegrid_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
     var selectedMovie = (MovieCat)e.ClickedItem;
     var nav = WindowWrapper.Current().NavigationServices.FirstOrDefault();
     nav.Navigate(typeof(MovieDetailPage),selectedMovie.title);
}
```

This is my code in the MovieDetailPage

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
      base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
      var parameter = (string)e.Parameter;
      string movietitle = parameter;
 }
```

When I run my code the parameter that is this string

```
"{\"Type\":\"System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e\",\"Data\":\"\\\"Avengers\\\"\"}"
```

I only want to get the movie title "Avengers". How do I separate it from this string.

Answer (score 0):

I fount the anwser to my own question in the following question.
[Template 10 Navigation Service Serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524171/template-10-navigation-service-serialization)

This is my change I had to do to my OnNavigatedTo method

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
     var parameter = (string)e.Parameter;
     movietitle = Template10.Services.SerializationService.SerializationService.Json.Deserialize<string>(parameter);
 }
```